# How to perform token authentication in elasticsearch?

Tags: authentication, curl, elasticsearch

I'm testing Elasticsearch in development mode with docker official image.

The basic install is based on X_pack and basic authentication.

Everything works fine by performing curl like:

```
curl -XPUT -u elastic:elasticpassword "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d'
{
  "title": "The Godfather",
  "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
  "year": 1972, "user":"elastic", "password":"changeme"
}'
```

But is there a way to perform a token request (with user and password) and then query Elasticsearch with the token. Instead of having to specify user/password every time I perform a query?

Answer (score 33):

The default X_Pack in docker image has Basic authentication enabled. Which is what your are using. The token for the same is base64(user:password). You can generate the same using http://base64encode.org and inputing :.

In curl there are two ways to call Basic auth URLs

```
curl -XPUT -u elastic:elasticpassword "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d''
```

which you have already been using

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic ZWxhc3RpYzpjaGFuZ2VtZQ==" -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d'....'
```

Now if your problem is putting in this again and again then you better create a alias in your bash profile like below

```
alias curles='curl  -u elastic:elasticpassword'
```

After that you can call your commands as below

```
curles -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d''
```

Comment: Thanks, the second curl your are proposing is exactly what I was looking for... but still I dont get where/ how you generated and found the token : e.g. "ZWxhc3RpYzpjaGFuZ2VtZQ=="

Comment: This is from the site http://base64encode.org/. Enter your 'username:password' and then click on encode. And you will get that value

Comment: Ok got it, basically it's the same way.... So there's no way to perform a authentication call to generate an authenticated session associated to a token? So I may simply rely on my token->authenticated session  instead of sending credentials every call....

Comment: Not in the default setup you are using. Not sure if you can configure some other auth plugin for OAuth2 or JWT in ElasticSearch

Comment: See if this url helps https://www.elastic.co/blog/user-impersonation-with-x-pack-integrating-third-party-auth-with-kibana

Answer (score 11):

Cutting out a lot of my original answer because you could argue it's all local, but leaving one major complaint about security here:

2. Definitely don't go to base64encode.org and enter your username:password. The very fact that it is suggested here on StackOverflow makes that site now (sadly for the owners) and incredibly juicy hacking target to compromise since they know people are going there.

Answer (score 6):

```
curl -X GET --user myuser:mypassword "http://elasticsearch:9200/_cluster/health?pretty"
```

In my case above curl helped

```
    {
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 16,
  "active_shards" : 16,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Further to Taran's answer, if you want to generate base64 token, you can do so by the following command:

```
echo -n 'username:pass' | openssl base64
```

Comment: If you are on Windows, open a cmd and type: powershell "[convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(\"username:password\"))"